# Combinatorics Question

Tags: combinatorics

(a)Show that there are ${m+n+1 \choose m+1}$ binary words with exactly $m$ 1's and at most $n$ 0's.
(b)Show that there are ${m + n + 2 \choose m + 1} -1$ binary words with at most $m$ 1's and at most $n$ 0's.

Comment: Your title and your "question" don't agree..

Comment: The title is correct while the body is not.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. If you have a string with exactly $m+1$ ones and exactly $n$ zeros you can convert it into a string with exactly $m$ ones and at most $n$ zeroes by deleting the last one, along with everything to its right. Prove that this transformation is bijective.